# How to determine where syslog messages are coming from?

Tags: fedora, syslog

I took over a Fedora server where the /var/log folder keeps growing to over 100gb of data and some of the logs are old.  I think some of them are logs being sent from our Firewall but how do I determine where all the messages are coming from?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, 100gb of logs in `/var/log` indicates that `logrotate` was either not implemented or misconfigured or broken for some reason. Logs in `/var/log` are subject to policies defined in configuration of `logrotate`. I would first look whether it is installed (it should be by default on many distros) and how exactly configured in configuration file - most commonly `/etc/logrotate.conf`.

Second problem is generation of so many log data. If firewall / iptables-netfilter is suspected search for `--log-prefix` in output of `iptables -L -n`. Take action accordingly.

Your problem may be long time present but never escalated, speaking from my personal experience.